# How to include the dash map tools to update a dash data table?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a dash app below.
The app for the moment updates a dash data table whenever the user clicks on the points on the map. I am a little stack in how to also use the dash map tools (box select and lasso select) to also update the table (keeping the click function too).
I have tried adding a new callback that includes the'selecteddata' function for the dash tools but it seems to stop all the previous callbacks.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
from dash import dash_table



pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'


df = pd.read_csv('Data1.csv')


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

app.title = "Project 1"

server = app.server



color = {'Mixed': '#e48900',
         'Arable': '#5aa469',
         'Livestock': '#8ab6d6'}

def update_bar(df):
    fig = go.Figure()
    for type in df['Type'].unique():
        df_by_Type = df[df['Type']==type]
        df_by_Type.sort_values('Capacity',inplace=True)
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar({
                              'x':df_by_Type['Capacity'],
                              'y':df_by_Type['Name'],
                              'orientation':'h',
                              'name':type,
                              'marker':{'color':color[type]},
                              # 'cumulative':{'enabled':True,'direction':'decreasing'}
                              # 'histfunc':'count'
        }))

    fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',height=900)
    fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='category descending')
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text='Hectares')

    return fig

def update_map(df):
    traces = []

    for type in df['Type'].unique():
       
        traces.append(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df['Latitude'],
        lon=df['Longitude'],
        mode='markers',
        customdata=df.loc[:, ['Type']],
        hovertemplate="<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" +"Type: %{customdata[0]}<br>" +""+ "<extra 
 </extra>",
        showlegend=False,
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                size=20,
                color=df['Code']
                ),
        text=df ['Name'],
        name = type
        ))

    return {'data': traces,
             'layout': go.Layout(hovermode='closest',
              height= 900,
              mapbox=dict(
                  accesstoken='MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN',
                  bearing=0,
             center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
                        lat=56.0,
                        lon=-4.0
                ),
            pitch=0,
            zoom=5
        ))}


app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    html.H1(['Project 1'],style={'text-align':'center'})
                ], width=15),
            ], align='center'),
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    html.Label(['Select Region'],style={'font-weight':'bold'},),
                     dcc.Dropdown(id='region-dropdown',
                                  options=[{'label':i,'value':i} for i in df['Region'].unique()],
                                  multi= True

                     )
                ], width=3),
                dbc.Col([
                   html.Div(
                            [
                            dbc.Button('Submit', id='submit-button', color='primary', className='mr-1')
                            ],style={'margin-top':'20px'}
                    )
                ], width=3),
            ], align='center'), 
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                     html.Div([
                  dcc.Graph(id = 'graph',figure=update_map(df))
                  ])
                ], width=7),
                dbc.Col([
                    html.Div([
                  dcc.Graph(id = 'graph-1',figure=update_bar(df))
                  ])
                ], width=5),
            ], align='center'), 
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([dash_table.DataTable(id='table',columns=[{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns],
                                               style_cell_conditional=[{'if': {'column_id': 'Code',} ,  'display': 'None',}],
        style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll'},
        style_cell={
            'minWidth': '100px', 'width': '100px', 'maxWidth': '90px',
            'height': 'auto',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis','textAlign': 'left',
            'fontSize':20, 'font-family':'sans-serif'
        })
                ], width=8),
              
            ], align='center'),      
        ])
    ) 
])



@app.callback([Output('graph','figure'),
              Output('graph-1','figure')],
              [Input('submit-button','n_clicks')],
              [State('region-dropdown','value')],
             )

def update_graph(n_clicks,region): 
    frames = []
    for region_name in region:
            frames.append(df[(df['Region']==region_name)])
    df_filtered = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index=True)
    return [update_map(df_filtered), update_bar(df_filtered)]


@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    Input('graph', 'clickData'),
    State('table', 'data'),
            )   

def update_table(selected_point, current_data):
    if selected_point is None:
        return current_data
    else:
        lat, lon = selected_point['points'][0]['lat'], selected_point['points'][0]['lon']
        selected_row = df[(df['Latitude'] == lat) & (df['Longitude'] == lon)]
        if selected_row.empty:
            return current_data
        else:
            return selected_row.to_dict('records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution by adding some elements in the call-back that updates the data table and adding another if statement in the data table update function.
I also added a clear data button that clears the selected data

```
@app.callback(
Output('table', 'data'),
Output('graph', 'selectedData'),  # Clear selected data from map
Input('graph', 'clickData'),
Input('graph', 'selectedData'),
Input('clear-data-button', 'n_clicks'),
State('table', 'data'),
 )
def update_table(click_data, selected_data, clear_data_clicks, current_data):
ctx = dash.callback_context

# Determine the triggered input
triggered_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

if triggered_id == 'clear-data-button':
    # Clear the table data and the selected data from the map
    return [], None

selected_rows = set()

if selected_data:
    if 'points' in selected_data:
        selected_points = selected_data['points']
        for point in selected_points:
            lat, lon = point['lat'], point['lon']
            selected_row = df[(df['Latitude'] == lat) & (df['Longitude'] == lon)]
            if not selected_row.empty:
                selected_rows.add(selected_row.index[0])

if click_data:
    lat, lon = click_data['points'][0]['lat'], click_data['points'][0]['lon']
    selected_row = df[(df['Latitude'] == lat) & (df['Longitude'] == lon)]
    if not selected_row.empty:
        selected_rows.add(selected_row.index[0])

if not selected_rows:
    return current_data, None  # Keep the current selectedData

selected_data = df.iloc[list(selected_rows)]
return selected_data.to_dict('records'), None  # Clear selectedData
```